# Data of Manipulating Arrays and Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to perform some data manipulation of an object/array by somewhat transposing the values. where the values of the rows become columns. As an example i have original data which looks like this

```js
[
  {
    "Team": "D PG",
    "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028": 194,
    "Month": "January"
  },
  {  "Team": "D PP",
    "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028": 143,
    "Month": "January"
  },
  {
    "Team": "D RE",
    "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028": 19,
    "Month": "January"
  },
  {
    "Team": "D GP",
    "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028": 3,
    "Month": "January"
  },
  {
    "Team": "D PC",
    "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028": 2,
    "Month": "January"
  },
  {
    "Team": "D PT",
    "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028": 2,
    "Month": "January"
  },
  {
    "Team": "D PG",
    "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028": 35,
    "Month": "February"
  },
  {
    "Team": "D PP",
    "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028": 120,
    "Month": "February"
  },
  {
    "Team": "D RE",
    "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028": 40,
    "Month": "February"
  },
  {
    "Team": "D GP",
    "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028": 30,
    "Month": "February"
  },
  {
    "Team": "D PC",
    "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028": 9,
    "Month": "February"
  },
  {
    "Team": "D PT",
    "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028": 6,
    "Month": "February"
  }
]
```

My intention to change this to

```js
//i'm looking at changing the original data to look like this. The Team will have a position on the array, for example array[0][1](this column will be taken by all values that belong to team 'D PG') and array[0][2](will be taken by all values that belong to the team 'D PP')

// you will notice that all the other values for other months are at zero, thats because i want the initial values to be zero untill data has been put in for them
[
  [
    "January",
    194,
    143,
    19,
    3,
    2,
    2
  ],
  [
    "February",
    35,
    120,
    40,
    30,
    9,
    6
  ],
  [
    "March",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  [
    "April",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  [
    "May",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  [
    "June",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  [
    "July",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  [
    "August",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  [
    "September",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  [
    "October",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  [
    "November",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  [
    "December",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ]
]
```

i use a for Loop to iterate the original Data object and then use if statements to group them by Month and Team. But the code will become very bulky and i believe inefficient. Any ideas on a better way to do this

```js
                 var grouped = eval('[["January",0,0,0,0,0,0],["February",0,0,0,0,0,0],["March"0,0,0,0,0,0],["April",0,0,0,0,0,0],["May",0,0,0,0,0,0],["June"0,0,0,0,0,0],["July",0,0,0,0,0,0],["August",0,0,0,0,0,0],["September",0,0,0,0,0,0],["October",0,0,0,0,0,0],["November",0,0,0,0,0,0],["December",0,0,0,0,0,0]]');

 
 for (i=0; i< dataResult.length; i++) {
                           
                           if((dataResult[i]['Month'] == 'January') && (dataResult[i]['Team'] == 'D PG')){
                               var original = dataResult[i]['Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028'];
                                grouped[0][1] =original;
                           }
                         if((dataResult[i]['Month'] == 'January') && (dataResult[i]['Team'] == 'D PP')){
                            var original = dataResult[i]['Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028'];
                                grouped[0][2] =original;
                         }
                         if((dataResult[i]['Month'] == 'January') && (dataResult[i]['Team'] == 'D RE')){
                               var original = dataResult[i]['Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028'];
                                grouped[0][3] =original;
                           }
                         if((dataResult[i]['Month'] == 'January') && (dataResult[i]['Team'] == 'D GP')){
                            var original = dataResult[i]['Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028'];
                                grouped[0][4] =original;
                         }
                          if((dataResult[i]['Month'] == 'January') && (dataResult[i]['Team'] == 'D PC')){
                               var original = dataResult[i]['Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028'];
                                grouped[0][5] =original;
                           }
                         if((dataResult[i]['Month'] == 'January') && (dataResult[i]['Team'] == 'D PT')){
                            var original = dataResult[i]['Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028'];
                                grouped[0][6] =original;
                         }
```

Comment: Why post a bunch of invalid sample data? Why is the value in the `February` month not included? Why is the `Team` part of the condition when you've included every team? Why does the desired result only have two `0` for most months, but your `grouped` has `6` for each month?

Comment: My sincere apologies, the question was asked in a hurry last night, i have corrected all of the data.  so basically i want the data to be grouped by Month and Team. My attempt involves ordering the team on specific columns in the array and Month on rows. But this makes the code very bulky. i was hoping i could get guidance on a more efficient way

Answer (score 0):

As always, just use a hashtable to easify things:

```
const result = [], month = {};

// I did not want to put that identifier everywhere... :/
const wtf = "Original_x0020_Size_x0020__x0028";

for(const entry of data){
  if(month[entry.Month]){
     month[entry.Month].push(entry[wtf]);
  } else {
     result.push(month[entry.Month] = [entry.Month, entry[wtf]]);
  }
}
```